# Random musing, is $\langle\psi^*|\psi\rangle$ = $\langle\psi^*|I|\psi\rangle$, where I is the identity operator a legit operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Just to have some consistency here, is 1 or the identity operator some sort of legitimate operator in quantum mechanics because so far I've only seen E, p or r as operators.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a real operator.

If you are working in some basis $\lvert i \rangle$, then you can write the identity operator as $I = \sum_{i} \lvert i \rangle\langle i \rvert$.

For example, say you've some ket $\lvert \psi \rangle$ that can be represented as $\lvert \psi \rangle = \sum_j a_j \lvert j \rangle$ in the basis, then we have

$$I\lvert \psi\rangle = \sum_{ij} a_j \lvert i \rangle\langle i \rvert j \rangle$$

but the basis vectors are orthogonal, so we have $\langle i \rvert j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$

Then, the sum over $j$ collapses, and we find:

$$I\lvert \psi\rangle = \sum_{i}a_i \lvert i \rangle = \lvert\psi\rangle$$

Comment: could you please kindly show why $I$ can be written as that goofy thing on the second line? thanks

Comment: I think this argument is actually the easiest way to see why it can be written this way. It might sound circular but we just want an operator that leaves any bra/ket vector it acts upon unchanged, and this goofy thing obviously does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is. In a two state system in some basis, it will be the 2x2 identity matrix. Which you'll surely agree is a matrix (aka a linear operator). Linear operators like H and x and p are just generalizations of matrices, even on continuous space.

Comment: Shouldn't the identity operator *always* be the identity matrix (i.e. in every basis)?

Comment: @BrianBi heyy I love your answers on quora! (If this is the same guy) Its just a point of contention whether to say "matrix" or "linear operator" whether you're in a finite dimensional, countably infinite, uncountably infinite Hilbert space, and whether you're given a basis, or not given a basis.

Comment: @BrianBi so I chose to be specific.